# Windows OS: Connected dev board not visible in mdt using Git Bash

Tags: windows, tpu, google-coral

Doc I followed - https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/#install-mdt
Python3 version: 3.9

**What I have done**

- Flashed the board with a microSD card.
- I have installed MDT and it is working fine.
- Connected the dev board via USB, confirmed a new Network Adapter (Remote NDIS Compatible
  Device) shows up in Device Manager
- Ran `mdt devices`

**What the docs said should happen**
connected dev board should be listed

**What actually happened**

- After waiting for some time nothing gets listed (mdt cannot see the
  connected device)
- Running `mdt wait-for-device` stalls in "Waiting for device..."
- Running `mdt shell` gives the error, "Waiting for a device... Unable to find any devices on your local network segment."

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way to do this, but this did the trick for me:

First connect your board to your PC.

Go to **Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center**

Here you will see an **Unidentified network** click on it and go to **Properties**.
In properties, go to **Sharing** and check **Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection**.

Now try running `mdt shell` command.
After you have successfully connected your board, make sure to uncheck the previous option in **Network Sharing**.

Answer (score 0):

I did the above but it did not fix my problem. Here is what fixed it -

Apparently the dev board is seen as a unidentified network under public networks. My Windows Firewall settings blocked python.exe from writing to or reading to public networks. I did the following -

**How to check if Windows Firewall is blocking a program**

Press Windows Key + R to open Run.
Type control and press OK to open Control Panel.
Click on System and Security.
Click on Windows Defender Firewall.
From the left pane Allow an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall.
In the allowed apps window, scroll through all the apps.
Locate the app you want to review and see if the app is checked.
(***Here the python.exe was not checked. I changed the setting and voila, mdt devices finds the device and everything works on from here.***)
If it is unchecked, the app is blocked on the Firewall.
If your program is blocked, simply check the app and click OK.